# Scanning Via IntentIntegrator never finishes

Tags: android, mobile, android-intent, zxing, qr-code

I have implemented some of the zebra crossing (zxing) code in an attempt to create an Android application that scans some barcodes. Pretty basic stuff really. Here are the fundamentals of my code:

```
    public void recognizeQRClick(View view) { 
    printingNewQR = false;
    recognizingQR = true;
    text1.setText("Recognize QR button clicked");

    IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    intentIntegrator.initiateScan();
    return;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE: 
        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanResult != null) {
            String contents = scanResult.getContents();
            if(printingNewQR) {
                return;
            } else if(recognizingQR){
                displayQRInfo(contents);
            }
            text1.setText(contents);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that, while the scanning portion appears to work (when the appropriate button is clicked, the app jumps to the scanning screen, and when the barcode is centered a small golden dot appears in the center to indicate a good scan) it never finishes. The app just remains in the scanning screen, scanning the same barcode over and over. I have googled this problem extensively and found a similar issue in a couple of instances, but always their problems seem to be fixed once they use the IntentIntegrator class, which I am doing. What is wrong?